# Display row data from gsheet colum via PHP

Tags: php

I saw this code and it's working fine when I need to show array. [from github](https://gist.github.com/pamelafox/770584/f1ae212019c3305edd90cdc20d2725da4f181a51)

```
<?php

$url = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1lDynpUNoMLoQrpCOsZYjCik6JcDlb6VcWATwI47View/1/public/values?alt=json';

$file= file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($file);
$rows = $json->{'feed'}->{'entry'};

foreach($rows as $row) {
  echo '<p>';
   $fname = $row->{'gsx$first'}->{'$t'};
   $lname = $row->{'gsx$last'}->{'$t'};
   $item = $row->{'gsx$order'}->{'$t'};
   $code = $row->{'gsx$track'}->{'$t'};
   $cid = $row->{'gsx$id'}->{'$t'};
  echo $cid . '<br>' . $fname . ' ' . $lname . '<br>' . $item . ' ' . 
$code;
  echo '</p>';
}
?>
```

Output is

```
123
Pedro Penduko
shoe 1001

456
Juan Dela Cruz
bag 1002
```

Can you help me to only output a specific user when I select a specific ID?

Comment: `if (cid == requireId) { output }`

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much! I added this. if ($cid == $_GET['cid']){
   echo $cid . '<br>' . $fname . ' ' . $lname . '<br>' . $item . ' ' . $code;
   echo '</p>';
   }

Answer (score 0):

```
if($cid == '123'){

      echo $cid . '<br>' . $fname . ' ' . $lname . '<br>' . $item . ' ' . 
$code;

}

//result

123

Pedro Penduko

shoe 1001
```

Answer (score 0):

This was answered by u_mulder.

So I added this.

```
  if ($cid == $_GET['cid']){
    echo $cid . '<br>' . $fname . ' ' . $lname . '<br>' . $item . ' ' . 
    $code;
    echo '</p>';
    }
```